# Pusher slows down ajax request with > 200ms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pusher

I'm having some trouble with [Pusher](http://pusher.com). Usually an AJAX request takes about 100 ms to my server, but when I run the trigger function in Pusher (to tell Pusher to push to all connected clients), requests are being slowed down by about 200-300 ms.

```
$pusher->trigger('presence-my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
```

Does it have to do with it being a presence channel?

Is there any way around this? What can I do server side respectively locally? Is there some AJAX settings I can alter? (I don't need to return a response to my AJAX request.)

Sometimes the request takes even 500ms, and if three of those are triggered almost at the same time things get slow.

Is there something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about knowing the result of the call to the Pusher web API and you simply want it to be made as fast as possible then you could consider making an Async call. A pull request has been raised to add this to the pusher-php-server library:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server/pull/11

I'd suggest adding a +1 to this pull request so that tests are written, it's merged into master and then a release is tagged.

Your other option is to push a message on to a message queue instead of calling the Pusher Web API directly. You can then have another daemon service which reads off the message queue and makes the request to Pusher. This will remove the delay caused by making an HTTP request to Pusher.

Comment: facing this same issue, but putting the jobs in a background queue will loose the whole charm around "realtime" updates :/

Comment: I am too facing this same problem, I was expecting Pusher to be faster than this, 500ms here too..  not impressed Pusher..  I'm ditching them for my needs.  the world operates faster than 500ms these days.. just ask google.  I say Pusher needs to get to 80ms MAX per trigger!

Comment: @hamish definitely one for Pusher Support